# Java XPath - Limit Scope - Saxon s9api

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

I am using Saxon's s9api package to do XPath lookup.

I want to limit my search to just 1 node and its descendants.

```
<root>
    <b>
        <a>foo</a>
    </b>
    <b>
        <a>bar</a>
    </b>
</root>
```

I am passed /root/b[2] as an XdmNode (bNode), and I am trying to search under it.

```
XPathSelector selector = new Processor(false).newXPathCompiler().compile(xPath).load();
selector.setContextItem(bNode);
selector.evaluate()
```

But I am always getting results from the Document root!

I have tried the following XPaths:

1. **/b/a**     -> Returns nothing
2. **b/a**      -> Returns nothing
3. **./b/a**    -> Returns nothing
4. **//b/a**    -> Returns both  elements

**Note:** I know I could get the passed XdmNode's index and put that in my XPath. But I want a search from the given XdmNode so that it can be done for any node in any document and I do not have to worry about how that node was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `./a` or just `a`. The context already references `b`, so your XPath number 3 would mistakenly try to find nested `b` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Both worked. Thank you!

And here I thought my problem was with **Java/Saxon** and not **XPath**. :/

Comment: Just to amplify this answer: a path expression that starts with "/" searches the document that contains the context item, *not* the subtree rooted at the context item. To search the subtree rooted at the context item, it should start with "./" (or just with an axis step).

Answer (score 0):

In my code it is like this:

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);
NodeList xpathResult = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The last line is the interesting one.

I'm not sure if this is saxon and/or the right version though. Might give it a shot :)

Comment: I am using Saxon because it supports up to version 3.1 of XPath.